# Getting data from table on input_post codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

So I'm creating an application for clients to fill in an order to calculate the price. The client has to fill in a form, the form will be posted to a table in MySQL. When the order is complete the client gets an overview of his order with the calculated price. I'm having trouble with storing a variable (from tblPanel_Prices) which is related with a variable in tblPaneltypes. So after filling in the form data from column tblPaneltypes and tblPanel_Prices should be stored together in another table. Both tables (types and prices) are related.

1. The client has to select a type of panel. These types are stored in the table (tblPaneltypes). Every panel has a certain price-categorie (field price_id) which is needed to calculate the price. The prices of the paneltypes are stored in another table (tblPanel_Prices). There is a relation between the tblPaneltypes and tblPanel_Prices (both integer)

So the client fills in the form and selects a certain type of panel, this gets posted (controller) to the table with the function: this->input->post('paneltype').

2. After this I want to calculate the surface of the panel and make select the right price-category on the field price-id.

So in the form there is a type of panel choosen by the client. This already goes to my table, but I also want to pass the price_id tag in the form.

Then, I would like to get the price_id tag from the table tblPaneltypes to link this with the price_id tag in tblPanel_Prices. The value of the price_id isn't important for the client, so no need to select or show this value. I just need it to calculate the price of the panel (which depends on the type of panel filled in by the client)

Thanks in advance!

Store function in controller

```
public function store()
    {
        $this->load->model("orders/panels/Panels");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('amount', 'aantal', 'numeric|required|max_length[2]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dwidth', 'paneelbreedte', 'numeric|callback_check_width');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dheight', 'paneelhoogte', 'numeric|callback_check_height');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('paneltype', 'paneeltype', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ral_code', 'ral kleur', 'callback_check_double');


        if ($this->auth()) {
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $this->read_panel();
            } else {
                $panel = $this->Panels->create__entry(
                    $this->input->post('order_id'),
                    $this->input->post('amount'),
                    $this->input->post('dwidth'),
                    $this->input->post('dheight'),
                    $this->input->post('paneltype'),
                    $this->input->post('panelcategory'),
                    $this->input->post('color'),
                    $this->input->post('othercolor'),
                    $this->input->post('tubes'),
                    $this->input->post('colorswatch'),
                    $this->input->post('structurepaint'),
                    $this->input->post('uv'),
                    $this->input->post('window'),
                    $this->input->post('paintwindow'),
                    $this->input->post('windowsetup'),
                    $this->input->post('glastype'),
                    $this->input->post('door')
                );
                redirect("rail/read_rail?order=" . $this->input->post('order_id'));
            }
        } else {
            login();
        }
```

create__entry in model:  at this moment I'm filling in the panelcategory manually in the model in. In the future it should filled in automaticly.

```
function create__entry($order_id, $amount, $dwidth,
                       $dheight, $paneltype, $panelcategory, $color,
                       $othercolor, $tubes,
                       $colorswatch, $structurepaint,
                       $uv, $windowtype, $paintwindow,
                       $windowsetup, $glastype, $door)
{
    $this->order_id = $order_id;
    $this->amount = $amount;
    $this->dwidth = $dwidth;
    $this->dheight = $dheight;
    $this->paneltype = $paneltype;
    $this->panelcategory = $panelcategory;
    $this->color = $color;
    $this->othercolor = $othercolor;
    $this->tubes = $tubes;
    $this->colorswatch = $colorswatch;
    $this->structurepaint = $structurepaint;
    $this->uv = $uv;
    $this->windowtype = $windowtype;
    $this->paintwindow = $paintwindow;
    $this->windowsetup = $windowsetup;
    $this->glastype = $glastype;
    $this->door = $door;

    $this->db->insert(self::TABLE_NAME, $this);
    return $this->read__entry($this->db->insert_id());
}
```

Comment: please show some code, what have you tried, were there any errors?

Comment: Ah, forgot the code! Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: You could precise what do you search. How to describe relation - add price id to tblPaneltypes table? or you want to make a dropdown inside the view to select the correct price? Or you want ajax action for the price to automatically calculate price?

Maybe make the question more clear if you can.

Comment: Editted the question, hopes this makes more sense. Pretty new to PHP so it's not so easy to explain what I want to do with the right words/commands. Thanks cssBlaster for the help! Actually I just need a way to insert the price_id colum from the tblPaneltypes in my table with my orders based on the selection of paneltype the client has made in the form.

Comment: I think the most you search for the outcome of this action, so you would rather show the                 rail/read_rail function - `redirect("rail/read_rail?order=" . $this->input->post('order_id'));` and the view.

Comment: The read_rail function is the next function to be shown. The total order exists out of 4 parts (first one is panel, the second one is rail). After completing all parts I'm showing a overview of the order on which I want to calculate the price. On this form I need the paneltype_price (which is linked with the price_id) from the first form (panel). But I have no clue how to store the price_id because it is related to the input (paneltype) of the client on the form